# Check if a variable is empty

Tags: php, html, forms

I have some user-submitted variables that I want to display in a different part of my site like this:

```
<div class="pre_box">Term: </div>
<div class="entry"><?php $key='term'; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?></div>
```

Occasionally, these variables might be empty in which case I don't want to display the label for the empty variable. In the example above I would want to hide the `<div class="pre_box">Term: </div>` part. Is there some simple way to check if a php variable like the one above is empty and prevent the label from being displayed?

Update, here is the code using !empty

```
<?php $key='term' ?>
<?php if( !empty( $key ) ): ?> 
<div class="pre_box">Term: </div>
<div class="entry">
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?>
</div> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

However, this still displays the content no matter what. I think the problem might be in the way I am defining the $key variable. Im trying to pull data from a custom field set in a wordpress post - thats what the $post->ID business is all about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php 
    $post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'term', true);
    if (!empty($post_meta)) {
?>
        <div class="pre_box">Term: </div>
        <div class="entry"><?php echo $post_meta; ?></div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Is there a short hand for it?

Answer (score 5):

If `isset()` does not work, try [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) instead:

```
<?php if( !empty( $key ) ): ?> 
    <div class="pre_box">Term: </div>
    <div class="entry">
         <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?>
    </div> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

`isset()` will deliver `TRUE` if the value is set and has a value different from `NULL`.

`empty()` instead will deliver `TRUE` (hence `!empty()` results in `FALSE`) for:

> - **`""` (an empty string)**
> - `0` (0 as an integer)
> - `"0"` (0 as a string)
> - `NULL`
> - `FALSE`
> - `array()` (an empty array)
> - `var $var;` (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)

I assume your `$key` is set but with an empty string. Thus, `empty()` is the way to go here.

Comment: @Thomas : Ok I see now. Of course, if you set `$key` beforehand, it will never be empty ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if( isset( $var ) ): ?><p><?php echo $var ?></p><?php endif; ?>
```

If $var is set it will display the paragraph with $var, otherwise nothing will be displayed

Comment: `<?php if( isset( $key ) ): ?>
<div class="pre_box">Term: </div><div class="entry"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>`

Comment: The text/variable is getting displayed whether or not the variable is set.

Answer (score 0):

Well they way your code is above, $key will never be empty, thus the pre_box will always be displayed. You're setting `$key = 'term'`, which gives it a value so `!empty($key)` or `isset($key)` will always be true.

Casey's solution should give you the result you're going for.

Answer (score -1):

`isset()` is used to check if a variable is set and is not null. It returns true if the variable exists and has a non-null value, and false otherwise.

On the other hand, `empty()` is used to check if a variable has a empty value. It returns true if the variable does not have a value or has a value that is considered empty (such as null, false, 0, '', array(), or unset()), and false otherwise.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This answer has been already provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2659899/285587). Please consider adding another answer only if existing answers are do not answer the question