# What is the PHP syntax to check "is not null" or an empty string?

Tags: php, variables, null, conditional-statements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if a variable is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659837/check-if-a-variable-is-empty)

Simple PHP question:

I have this stement:

```
if (isset($_POST["password"]) && ($_POST["password"]=="$password")) {
...//IF PASSWORD IS CORRECT STUFF WILL HAPPEN HERE
}
```

Somewhere above this statement I use the following line in my JavaScript to set the username as a variable both in my JavaScript and in my PHP:

```
uservariable = <?php $user = $_POST['user']; print ("\"" . $user . "\"")?>;
```

What I want to do is add a condition to make sure $user is not null or an empty string (it doesn't have to be any particular value, I just don't want it to be empty. What is the proper way to do this?

I know this is a sill question but I have no experience with PHP. Please advise, Thank you!

Comment: please use the search function before asking question as you have been prompted to in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice. This has been asked and answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=check+for+empty+value+php

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Null OR an empty string?

```
if (!empty($user)) {}
```

Use empty().

---

After realizing that $user ~= $_POST['user'] (thanks matt):

```
var uservariable='<?php 
    echo ((array_key_exists('user',$_POST)) || (!empty($_POST['user']))) ? $_POST['user'] : 'Empty Username Input';
?>';
```

Comment: It looks like I read the question differently than everyone else... we're talking about $user, not $_POST['user'], right?

Comment: `$user` is assigned to `$_POST['user']` in his code. Might as well validate before assignment but it really doesn't matter

Comment: hmm, what's the difference, exactly? if I'm doing something wrong please tell me!

Comment: @mattedgod - Good point.  I missed that.

Comment: I like this way. I want this to be right. But I'm still getting errors. Unexpected ";" ... and I don't understand this part: 'Empty Username Input'

Comment: I had a typo. Missed a paren.  Try the code again.  As far as 'Empty Username Input', that's just a string I chose to represent an empty user variable.  If you want to use program flow to do something other than echo it out, we'd have to shift the code around a bit.

Answer (score 34):

Use [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php). It checks for both empty strings and null.

```
if (!empty($_POST['user'])) {
  // do stuff
}
```

From the manual:

> The following things are considered to be empty:

```
"" (an empty string)  
0 (0 as an integer)  
0.0 (0 as a float)  
"0" (0 as a string)    
NULL  
FALSE  
array() (an empty array)  
var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)
```

Comment: Note that if 'user' is not set on $_POST, you'll get a warning.  It'll still work, but it will fill up your logs quickly.  I usually mitigate this with:
`if ((array_key_exists('user',$_POST)) || (!empty($_POST['user']))`

Comment: all three of these are giving me error messages:

Comment: if (isset($_POST["password"]) && ($_POST["password"]=="$password") && (array_key_exists('user',$_POST))    and      if (isset($_POST["password"]) && ($_POST["password"]=="$password") && (!empty($_POST['user']))    and (isset($_POST["password"]) && ($_POST["password"]=="$password") && (!empty('$user'))

Comment: i didn't check the logs, when i go to the page i see "php sytax error on line 173"