# How to disable title if MySql field is blank/null/none

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display profile from MySql database using PHP, here is the simple code:

```
<b>Professional Society Membership:</b> <br>
<?php echo htmlentities($result->society_member);?>
```

Now I do not want to display **Professional Society Membership** if the MySql field "society_member" is empty / blank.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a variable is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659837/check-if-a-variable-is-empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check before your add the content of it is empty

```
<?php
    if (!empty($result->society_member)) {
?>
    <b>Professional Society Membership:</b> <br><?php echo htmlentities($result->society_member);
}?>
```

Comment: Many many thank you nbk, actually I am novice in PHP & MySQL